# Detecting screen resolution

Tags: css, html, positioning

I came across the website http://www.swiftkey.net.

On my widescreen I see the gray background on the sides of the content area..On my regular(1024x768) the grey bars are not there.

How do they acheive this effect?

Using firebug, I was able to decipher what I think MIGHT be doing this:

```
.w1 {
    float: left;
    width: 1600px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
.w2 {
    float: left;
    width: 1600px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I do have experince with CSS and HTML, but the above code is a little bit cryptic to me, especially considering w2 is inside w1.

Comment: Agreed use media queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering this under the assumption that the grey bars you're talking about are the ones shown in the second sample image:

[image: Sample Screenshot 1]
[image: Sample Screenshot 2]

---

The simple answer is that the page uses a wrapper with a static maximum width that is horizontally centered:

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto; //centers a block element
}
```

The grey bars are created by having a background color on the `<body>` or `<html>` elements:

```
body {
    background-color: #888;
}
```

I haven't checked the source to see where these styles are specifically set, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You forgot to mention that text-align:center; must be set on the containing element for margin:0px auto; to center an element.

Comment: are you sure? Not all browsers will automatically center content with that command alone will they? I spent ages looking at how to center my web pages and the text-align:center; popped up several times across the web as the best and most widely supported solution.

Comment: @DominicB-c, the element needs to either have a static width, or a maximum width, and additionally use `display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

This has to accomplished with javascript screen object

```
var scr=window.screen;
var availwidth=scr.availWidth;
var width=scr.width;
var availh=scr.availHeight;
var height=scr.height;
```

availWidth and availHeight gives actual available width and height, considering taskbars and scrollbars etc.
width and height give the actual screen resolution. Then access the variables and decide the type of layout.

However adjusting anything to center is easy

```
div
{
width:1024px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-512px;
}
```

the javascript screen width tracing is for more control options

Comment: You don't need JavaScript make CSS behave differently on different resolutions.

Comment: Yes but the title said detecting screen resolution, so I added the js part, u see.

Comment: The title is misleading. Read the question and answer appropriately.